# MySQL upgrade stuck at version selection

Tags: 14.04, apt, mysql

I am trying to upgrade my packages on Ubuntu 14.04 , Then MySQL is asking me to choose the server's version that I want to receive , I am stuck there , can't select any option [Including none]

Tried to uninstall MySQL but the following error appears :

> dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a'
>   to correct the problem

[image]

Comment: The dpkg advice you were given is worth trying. Proceed with it and see what happens next. If it doesn't work you can paste additional information here.

Comment: It opens the same stage (Choosing the version) ... It needs me to complete the upgrade

Comment: Just to be sure: if you press the tab key and/or the cursor keys then the red bar doesn't move? Because in the screenshot you've selected the first option and are about to accept it.

Comment: Yes it highlights the selection , however I can't confirm it with the OK

Comment: I did get that from your screenshot. I asked the question to try to establish if you can move the red bar. So can you? If 'yes' then you're not stuck. If 'no' then a more difficult operation is necessary.

Comment: I can move it for sure , but the three selections can't be confirmed with the <OK>

Comment: I mean try to select the second or third option (the red bar is on any of them) move the bar with the tab key  to 'ok' (so the red bar is on 'ok' and the previously selected option is now purple) and press the enter key on your keyboard.

Comment: Doing this with any of the three selections doesn't confirm and makes the red bar goes to the selections again to choose from them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this first:

`apt-get purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common mysql-client-5.5 mysql-server-5.5`

then reinstall mysql server.

If this doesn't work only then try the following:

`sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common`

or :

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql*
```

followed by :

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

If you want to preserve the configuration files then omit the '--purge' part in the first line.

Then to reinstall:

`sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install mysql-server

sudo mysql_install_db

sudo /usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation`

**warning: I never had to use the second method myself. Make a decent backup of your databases, if you have any, before trying this.**

Comment: The problem is , it seems that I can't use apt right now , all the previous purge commands tells me the error `dpkg was interrupted...` 
,
Running `sudo dpkg --configure -a` opens the same ' MySQL Upgrade window ' (that is in the screenshot)

Comment: Try the first command in the answer post please and if you think it doesn't work make a screenshot showing the output. The command is supposed to work always otherwise you wouldn't have an option to correct problems.

Comment: ok just a second try with `sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql*` worked today , Thanks man